# Combine counties in geographic data

Tags: r, maps, geospatial

I would like to represent multiple counties in TN state as a single region using a common color fill. I can do that with the code below:

```
library(maps)
map("state", "tennessee", fill = TRUE, col="white", names = TRUE, plot = TRUE)
co <- map("county",region = c("tennessee,williamson","tennessee,davidson",
                         "tennessee,wilson","tennessee,cheatham"),
       col = "red", bg = "blue", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
polygon(co$x, co$y, col = "yellow", border = "black")
```

But the black borders are drawn inside my region of interest. Is there a way to define the polygon function such that common county borders are not drawn in black?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using help.search() to find functions that support "clipping".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get the outside border of the whole ROI, you need a call to `map.poly()` with `as.polygon=FALSE`, and then plot this with `lines()`.
- To get the solid inside fill you need a call to `map.poly()` with `as.polygon=TRUE` and then plot this with `polygon()` and `border=FALSE`.

You can see this if you look through the code of `map` by just entering it at the command line and hitting enter.

Here is the code I used to get what you want:

```
map("state","tennessee",fill=T,col="white",names=T,plot=T)
coords = map.poly("county",region=c("tennessee,williamson","tennessee,davidson","tennessee,wilson","tennessee,cheatham"), boundary=T, interior=F, fill=F, as.polygon=T)
polygon(coords, col='red', border=F)
map("county",region=c("tennessee,williamson","tennessee,davidson","tennessee,wilson","tennessee,cheatham"),fill=F,interior=F,add=T)
```

[image]

From reading `?map`, I thought simply doing something like `map(..., interior=F, fill=T, col='red')` would work, but this doesn't seem to do it. Could be a bug, but I haven't played with this package enough to know for sure...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read the R Spatial Task View, and also use package:maptools to read and plot Shapefiles. Then you can either use package:rgeos to dissolve boundaries of a county shapefile or get a county and a state shapefile and plot them separately.

The old 'maps' package is a bit limited.

Comment: It does include a shapefile of the world. Is there a freely available shapefile as an alternative, when not using the maps package?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Check out http://www.gadm.org . Lots of good stuff to download, and you can choose versions that are already in R format.